# Can I assign program to shut down icon in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, script, shutdown

A simple question: Can I assign a script to the shut down icon in windows 10? I'm talking about the icon and not the physical power button on the machine.

Currently, when I click on the windows icon in the bottom left hand corner of the screen and then click on the standard start/stop button I get the usual three options to Sleep, Shutdown or Restart. What I would like is that if I clicked on, say, the word Shutdown a special script would be run that did some housekeeping before the machine actually shutdown. I know I can add scripts to the group policy for shutdown and restart with gpedit.exe but the scripts are not working. I could also create a specific script on, say, the desktop that I could click which in turn would do the required housekeeping and then shutdown the PC. However I would like to keep the standard procedure for shutting down the PC so other users of the PC don't have to be told the special way to shutdown the system.

Any help much appreciated.

Many thanks

gauss76

Comment: The answer given below by @Richard should be accepted.  It may or may not work, but he has clearly identified the only possibility of doing specifically what you asked.  --> Now let me ask whether you would be just as happy with an on-screen icon that would run a script that has the shutdown command at the end?  That would be a guarantee that it would finish before getting clobbered by the shutdown process.

Comment: I think any other users would fully understand the function of a nice icon that is labeled SHUTDOWN or LOG OUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided your script runs quickly, you could create a scheduled task which is triggered when event ID 1074 is logged. This is the ID that indicates the computer is shutting down.

There are some instructions on how to create this type of scheduled task [here](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/automatically-run-script-on-internet-connect-network-connection-drop/).

If your task runs for too long, then you ***might*** be able to get around this by aborting the original request in your script by starting with `shutdown /a` then disabling the scheduled task (using `schtasks`), running your script and then finishing with a call to `shutdown`. Assuming this even works (I've not tested it) you'll need a new scheduled task which runs at startup which re-enables the shutdown task.

Comment: That is very clever, @Richard.  Your caveats are verdad, to the point that I can't help but wonder if it is impossible.  Upvote for showing the only possibility.

Comment: Thanks @Richard. I finally wrote an AutoIt script and placed it on the taskbar as far left as possible. The script checks for any connected USB drives then performs shutdown, sleep etc if none are connected otherwise it warns to remove them before continuing.